# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I ask this Question because it is Moles specific.
Running VS2010 on Windows 7 64bit the VsHost of moles stays in the task manager, causing this message:

**Unable to copy file
The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by another process**

Solution: Kill the Process **Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.x86.exe** in the Task-Manager

To do this very often is very very annoying. I read in the msdn social forum that this issue shall be fixe sometime (i recall the post was from 2010 but cant find the post).

This happens nearly every time I stop the Debugging of the Test or if there is an Error while Debugging.

**Anything new about this Issue?**

I very much hope that Moles will be a standard part of Visual Studio someday, because I like this Typemocking very much!

Comment: Yes! the only solution is to kill the Process Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.x86.exe. But donno when it's gonna fixed!